# Lift - Display notice after signup

Tags: scala, lift

Using Lift, I would like to display a notice to a user after they sign up with something like:

```
S.notice("Thank you for signing up")
```

Where would I put this code, or is there another way I should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to put it anywhere in your code to be output on the current page. However, if your code handles the form submission and then redirects to a separate page - you would probably need something like this:

```
S.redirectTo("/confirm", () => S.notice("Thank you for signing up"))
```

This will issue the redirect with state. The above executes the function after the redirect - causing the message to be displayed.

In the case of ProtoUser, there are a few places in the API (http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.mapper.MegaProtoUser) that seem like they would work:

```
 user.toForm("Create User", 
   (u:UserType) => S.notice("Thank you for signing up"))
```

or you could try calling (or overriding if you want it permanently) this method:

```
  doPostCommit(() => S.notice("Thank you for signing up")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response =) that will be useful, but I was hoping for a solution involving the location where this line would be placed, when using the built-in ProtoUser model. For example, a method to override

Comment: I updated the answer with some places you could use this with MegaProtoUser.